# What means error "No route to host" paramiko.ssh_excepton.SSHException?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Each trying to connect I get error "paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to HOST: [Errno 113] No route to host"

This is the code I use:

```py
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()

self.t = paramiko.Transport((self.server_config["host"],
                             self.server_config["port"]))

self.t.connect(username=self.server_config["user"],
               password=self.server_config["password"])

self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

self.ssh.connect(username=self.server_config["user"],
                 password=self.server_config["password"],
                 hostname=self.server_config["host"],
                 port=self.server_config["port"])

self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.t)

self.load_folder_from_server()
```

Parameters in `self.server_config` are correct, I've checked them a million times.

Comment: "No route to host" isn't specific to Python or paramiko; it comes from your operating system's network layer, and it means _exactly_ what it says: that the routing table doesn't provide a way to get to the given destination address. If your destination address is truly correct, it's a host configuration or networking problem, not a software development problem; notably, only software development problems are on-topic here.

Comment: Can you ping the host? This error message typically just means that the network connection is impossible.

Comment: (BTW, why are you connecting twice? Either build a transport at the low level _or_ use the high-level interface; there's no reason to do both).

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that there is no route between the computer you are running this code on and the computer you are trying to connect to.